# iOS Stroke text in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uilabel, stroke

I'm trying to stroke text inside of a UILabel in iOS 7.1. I can't figure out why it isn't working... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[stringAttributes setObject: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20] forKey: NSFontAttributeName];
[stringAttributes setObject: [UIColor whiteColor] forKey: NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
[stringAttributes setObject: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2.0] forKey: NSStrokeWidthAttributeName];
[stringAttributes setObject: [UIColor blackColor] forKey: NSStrokeColorAttributeName];

[label.text drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50) withAttributes:stringAttributes];
```

Comment: Define "not working". Verify both `label` and `label.text` are not `nil`.

Comment: Neither are nil. The stroked text is not displayed on the screen.

Comment: What is the color of the view this text is being drawn on? I ask because you specify a stroke color of black and a foreground color of white. I'm not sure which will be used to actually draw the text. Try changing colors to see if it shows up.

Comment: There is a UIImageView that is used as the background. I moved it down to be sure it wasn't behind it.

Comment: When are you calling this `drawInRect:withAttributes:`? If there isn't currently a graphics context on the stack then you're not likely to see anything. This needs to be called inside a views `drawRect:` method or a layers `drawInContext:` (or the CALayers delegate method). Alternatively you can set up your own graphics context, but this won't draw to the screen.